# Event binding with dynamic ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some some divs which are dynamically created from a PHP script and displayed to a page via AJAX. These divs have a link on it to open a modal. When the page first loads the links work great. When the script updates and there is new data to display on the page the links for the new data do not work. Therefore I have found out I need to bind the event via .on(click).

Here is my problem I am running into since they are not static IDs to bind to. The IDs are dynamically produced based on the ID from a JSON file that is created from a 3rd party API.

```
    $AlertData .= "<div class='alert__view' id='eventID'>\n";
    $AlertData .= "<a href='#{$eventID}' data-toggle='modal' data-backdrop='false' data-target='#{$eventID}'><i class='fa fa-info-circle'></i></a>\n";
    $AlertData .= "</div>\n";
```

$eventID is the ID for the link and for the modal which it is linked to in order to open. So how would I go about binding a dynamic ID to this which is generated via PHP from parsing a JSON file? Now one thing I know is since the link uses a dynamic ID I can bind the function to one of it's parents. In this case 'eventID' but this still leaves me with the target ID being dynamically generated and I am not sure of a way to handle this or should I wrap the modal in a new so I can assign a parent ID to handle this?

Here is the snippet of code that updates the PHP file to display the updated data/information on the page PLUS the added event binding as I think it should be.

```
$.ajax({
          url: "inc/alertsTX.php",
          cache: false,
          success: function(data){
             $("#svrAlertsTX").html(data);
               $('#eventID'.on('click', function () {
                  $(#$eventID).html(data);
          }
         }
        });
```

Comment: you have an error here `$('#eventID'.on('click', function () {` , replace by   `$('#eventID').on('click', function () {`

Comment: You don't really have to use an ID, attach a class to all the elements and use that instead when attaching event handlers

Comment: I would better add a class for all those div, so you can do `$(document).on("click", ".my_class_for_my_divs", function(){/*do something here*/})`. Attaching click event on document will make it fire even with new DOM elements. If you cant add a class let me know so I will explain the other way (large way)

Answer (score 0):

Use `selector` when binding

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

like this

```
$('.alert__view').on('click', 'a', function () { ...
```

or you can bind upper (not recommended)

```
$('body').on('click', '.alert__view > a', function () { ...
```

From [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector.
>
> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

Comment: So would something like this be correct assigning the target to the parent class of the modal? $('.alert__view').on('click', 'a', function () {
   $('.alert-modal').html(data);
 });

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: I had a day to test this and unfortunately it is still not working. Should I put this in the Ajax script that does the refresh or in the php script that is being refreshed?